# sh/bash How to write if loop properly to get inputs and how to implement the script for infinite loop

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Basically, I'm trying to

1. get access permission to gpios
2. set directions as an output

then implementing an infinite loop for user interface

it should get user input of `lid` and `onoff`

then it should break if `lid` is less than 1

if the input is on, it should give 1 value to gpio

if the input is off it should give 0 value to the gpio

then after the end of loop, it should set directions as input and unexport the gpios

My problem is that whenever I try to implement the script, the first thing it do is setting exporting gpios and setting its value to 1, then asking me for `lid` and `onoff` input, the `lid` input don't change anything and after entering the on off input no matter what my inputs are the the gpio values set to 0

I also tried to use `while true; do  done` for infinite loop but I had a problem with it

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "30" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "31" > /sys/class/gpio/export

echo "high" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio30/direction
echo "high" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio31/direction

read -p "light_iid" int lid
read -p "on/off" str onoff; 
if ! [ $lid ‐lt 1 ]; 
then 
   break
fi 
if [ $onoff != "on" -a $onoff != "off" ]; 
then 
   break
fi
if ! [ $onoff_str == "on" ]
then 
   echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio30/value
   echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio31/value     
fi
if ! [ $onoff_str == "off" ]
then 
   echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio30/value
   echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio31/value
fi

echo "low" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio30/direction
echo "low" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio31/direction

echo "30" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
echo "31" > /sys/class/gpio/unexport
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, what's the concrete question. You are asking about a loop, but there is no looping construct in your code. Also, you are tagging your post as `bash`, but the script posted seems to assume  Posix shell.

Comment: `read -p` and using `==` with `[` are `bash` extensions; the `-a` argument to `test` is considered obsolete, even in POSIX.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds multiple problems with the code.  Fix the problems that it identifies.  I'll suggest a few fixes.  Use `#!/bin/bash` as the shebang line.  Put the line `set -o nounset` at the start so you will get warnings about uninitialized variables.  Remove `int` from the `read` command to read `lid`.  Remove `str` from the `read` command to read `onoff`.  (You can't specify variable types with the `read` command.)  Replace all uses of `$onoff_str` with `$onoff`.

Comment: The line `while true; do`, followed by the lines of the loop body, followed by the line `done`, is a valid way to implement an infinite loop.You need to provide details of the "problem with it" that you encountered.